# Unable to write to files in C++ dll project under C# Windows Application

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, file-io

I have a C++ dll project, which will be called by the C# Windows Application. But each time when I tried to write to files in the C++ dll project, I will get the following error:

> `An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in Wrapper.dll`
>
> `Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.`

[image]

When receiving this error, the code pointers to the `_Lock()` of file `fstream`:

[image]

The code I am using in the C++ dll project is:

```
ofstream ofs("debug.txt");      // OK
if (ofs.good())                 // OK
    ofs << "aaa" << endl;       // this line causes the error  <--
ofs.close();
```

Other info:

1. Developed under VS2010-Winx64 (.NET Framework 4).
2. `Wrapper` is the managed C++ project that wrappers the C++ code for being called in C#.
3. I checked the `debug.txt` file, which is writable.

Any suggestion is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Check that you actually have permission to write into the folder the application is running from. Could literally be a Windows access problem or the file is readonly?

Comment: You are passing a value where a pointer is expected...

Comment: @leppie I don't get it. Where did I pass a value?

Comment: I dont know, but that is the most common cause. I have also seen it happen in some multithreading scenarios involving SQLCE.

Comment: @leppie But, every time, it will fail in the exact same line `ofs << "aaa" << endl;`. There should be something to do with it, right?

Comment: Does the same code fail calling it from a C++ test harness? Is the actual string `"aaa"` or something you pass in from C#? Also, use mixed-mode debugging, you can quickly check what does not look like a point that should.

Comment: @leppie `"aaa"` is the actual string I used. And it works well from C++ test harness.

Comment: @leppie P.S. Removing these file-io lines will work well.

Comment: By far the most common reason for an AV is heap corruption.  It is never caused by the code that triggers the exception.  Not having to debug such Heisenbugs is of course an important reason that managed code is popular :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I am mixed up in setting the runtime library. Changing the runtime library from `/MD` to `/MDb` of the C++ dll project fixed the problem.

In VS2010, this can be done in:

```
Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ 
        -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library -> Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)
```